# Giving users specific view on a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to give a specific view on a list to different users. Because I have this custom list of people who handle servers. My team should be the only one to see their contact numbers and all other users will only see their names, servers they handle and other information.

What I currently did is give my team a specific url that directs them to a view that shows all the information and give the other users a url that only shows limited information. But I have one problem they can still see the all the views available so they can choose "All items" view and they can see all the information.
[image]

What I want to happen is, Either hide this view list or if there is any other way to give a user a specific list view base on their permission in the site or if they are not on my team

Comment: have you tried solution by using target audience. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3730d47f-6ba2-4ffd-ac05-567b042ff5c1/how-to-restrict-permissions-on-list-views?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Comment: Thank you for this information. But I can't seem to find Modify Shared Webpart. So I create a new page and just insert a web part and link the list. I successfully removed the views for the users to choose from but the search bar feature is lost. is there a way to bring it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking use target audience settings.

1. Edit your view page.
2. Go to list view web part properties
3. Go to "Advanced" section.
4. Add your group to the target audience.

Comment: but if they still go to display page of the item, they can see all information. So make sure to hide them on edit / display page.